# How to use a ListView inside a ExpandableList?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I've been working with a custom ExpandableList (see example picture below) where each item always has one child. This child consists of three parts. Each part has a header (red bars) and below that an Empty item OR a list of items. The length of this list will vary.

The first way I tried to do this is by adding a ViewStub below the empty item, which I inflated with a custom view, which also contained a ViewStub at the end which I inflated in turn for the next item, thus adding items recursively to create this sort of list of items. Sadly this resulted in StackOverflowError's when the list became too long (With short lists this worked perfectly).

So on my second try I tried using a ListView with a custom adapter instead. Sadly this list only used a small part of my screen and the rest of the items where occluded behind the header of the next part (This mini list looked scrollable as a second scrollbar appeared next to it, but it did not scroll. Not that I would consider this scrolling inside a scrolling list to be a good solution, but just wanted to mention this).

Can anyone tell me how I can tell this list of items to not be scrollable and take up all the room that it needs (does it know what size it is going to be when the child node is created??) or help me with a alternative solution to my problem? (Ooh, and I have considered putting an unholy amount of ViewStubs inside my layout, but that just seems idiotic and really bad practice. Correct me if I'm wrong)

[image]

Comment: hii,I have something similar implemented however my child listview is not scollable!!!am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then why don't you just take an ExpandableList + Adapter that implements ExpandableListAdapter? It's a somewhat ugly approach but it works and isn't much hassle.

> MyAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

}
```

In this method you could simply figure out if the current childPosition would be one of the headers or one of the children and inflate the appropriate View from xml.

Comment: Hey, I already had my own implementation of the ExpandableListAdapter, but previously just handled each child node as one element (one element with 3 headers and 3 lists), but I think your right that I should treat them as n+m+o+3 child nodes (where n, m and o are the size of the first, second and third list, respectively) and then check for each node which number they are to decide how to handle them. It will be harder to reuse the "convertView" with this solution though.